# Java For Loop Termination Condition: == vs <= vs >=

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

```
for (int i = lowerBound; i == upperBound; i++) {
      //Code goes here  
    }
```

I want the last time the for loop is run to have i equaling upperBound. Is this the right syntax? If so why might one ever use <= or >=? 
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: No, that's not going to work.  <= would work, though.

Comment: i <= upperbound+1 ? normally because arrays in several language start from 0th index and their size is then actual size -1. So we can write `for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)`

Comment: Have you tried the code? This will not work because the loop will only continue while the condition is true. Unless `upperbound == lowerbound`, this will never happen.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it would actually work for just 1 case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop can always be translated to a while loop as follows:

```
for(initialization; condition; step) {
   block;
}
```

To

```
initialization;
while (condition) {
   block;
   step;
}
```

So if your condition is `i == upperBound`, the loop will never run, because the condition doesn't start out as true.  <= will do what you want, though.

Comment: So the for loop will only run when the condition is true, the stop executing when it finds the condition to be false?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = lowerBound; i == upperBound; i++) {
      //Code goes here  
    }
```

The part inside for loop executes when it checks the constraint/condition mentioned inside for loop statement.

Example

```
for( int i =0; i == 10 ; i++){
    saySomething();
}
```

will run only when `i == 10` ie i would have been `i=10` , while if you had written `i<10` or `i<=10` it would have run each time that condition is true.

Here is a quick example : [link](http://ideone.com/23OBYR) for `for` loop.

Comment: I don't care that it's some C derivative, it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

To run all + equals to upperBound, you need to use <=

One may might use >= if you're counting backwards, <= and if you're counting forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
*i <= upperBound*
inside the loop.

The reason being that the loop is testing against all constraints in that loop and will only run when it ticks these off as being true. i is only equal to upperbound in one case and never while i it is also equal to lowerbound, so it won't run.

(Eek. First ever answer here! I hope this helps!)

Comment: Since I'm testing some numbers within a range I see why My code is not going to help me.